# void operator usage for calling menu

Tags: c++

So I have this part of code and I have these error than I'm to post how can I fix them . Thx for ur help..

```
void DisplayMenu()
{
    cout <<"Please choose from the following options :\n\n"
         <<"1-al.\n"
         <<"2-c.\n"
         <<"3-v.\n\n"
         <<"Or I want to see first :\n"
         <<"------------------------\n\n"
         <<"4-r.\n"
         <<"5-m.\n"
         <<"6-k.\n"
         <<"7-d.\n"
         <<"8-u.\n\n"
         <<"Or :\n"
         <<"----\n\n"
         <<"9-I changed my mind and would like to exit.\n\n";
}

int ChooseFromMenu()
{
    int A =0 ;
    while ((DisplayMenu() && !(cin >> A ) || (cin.good() && (A < 1 || A > 9))) {
    cout << "\nInvalid input!\n"<<endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    }
    return A;
}
```

and this is my error list

```
3   IntelliSense: expected a statement  
2   IntelliSense: expected a ')'  
Error   1   error C4716: 'DisplayMenu' : must return a value
```

Comment: Basically, don't try writing C# as if it's C++. Call `Console.WriteLine` multiple times instead.

Comment: (And then fix the error that you've got a method that's meant to return a `bool`, but you're not returning anything...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he just missused C# tag and he meant to use C++ tag.

Comment: sorry I want it to be void i will change that now . How can I use the void and modify that to  display menu each time wrong input is entered?

Comment: Okay, so now one of your error messages will go away... please provide a [mcve] which you've *actually compiled* (rather than code *like* something you've compiled). Also, pay attention to source layout...

Comment: soory can u explain what u mean??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question mainly because of two reasons : 1. It's offtopic because question is basically "Why is my code not working" and 2. OP doesn't know how to properly use StackOverflow.

Comment: come on men I'm just asking question Its not just about error I will ask other thing but I can't do a new topic each time right??? I never used a forum before u can help if u want thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to use `DisplayMenu` in the condition of the while loop, you need to use the comma operator:

```
int ChooseFromMenu()
{
    int A =0 ;
    while (DisplayMenu(), (!(cin >> A ) || (cin.good() && (A < 1 || A > 9))) {
        cout << "\nInvalid input!\n"<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');

    }
    return A;
 }
```

This will call `DisplayMenu`, throw the (non-existant) return value away, and then evaluate the actual condition.  Personally however, I would use an infinite loop with a conditional break inside:

```
int ChooseFromMenu()
{
    int A =0;
    while (true) {
        DisplayMenu();
        if ((cin >> A)) {
            if (!cin.good() || (1 <= A && A <= 9)) {
                return A;
            }
        }
        cout << "\nInvalid input!\n"<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    }
}
```

I have split the condition into two embedded `if`s because I find that easier to read than combinations of `&&` and `||`.  (I also like to always use `<` or `<=` when combining multiple comparisons - I find it makes it easier to read.)

Answer (score 1):

You're missusing condition in your `while` loop parameter :

```
while ((DisplayMenu() && !(cin >> A ) || (cin.good() && (A < 1 || A > 9)))
```

As you can see from the definition your `DisplayMenu` is returning `void` and you are trying to compare it to `boolean` value ( here -> `while ((DisplayMenu()` ).

To solve this you can change your `DisplayMenu` method to just return `boolean` value :

```
bool DisplayMenu()
{
    // your logic

    return true;
}
```

[Complete working example](http://cpp.sh/577fm) :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int DisplayMenu()
{
    cout <<"Please choose from the following options :\n\n"
                 <<"1-al.\n"
                 <<"2-c.\n"
                 <<"3-v.\n\n"
                 <<"Or I want to see first :\n"
                 <<"------------------------\n\n"
                 <<"4-r.\n"
                 <<"5-m.\n"
                 <<"6-k.\n"
                 <<"7-d.\n"
                 <<"8-u.\n\n"
                 <<"Or :\n"
                 <<"----\n\n"
                 <<"9-I changed my mind and would like to exit.\n\n";

    return 1;
 }

int ChooseFromMenu()
{   
    int A =0 ;
    if ((DisplayMenu() && !(cin >> A )) || (cin.good() && (A < 1 || A > 9))) {
        cout << "\nInvalid input!\n"<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');

    }
    return A;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting display should return a value ??

Comment: @davidfoster update your question with editted code and I'll check what's causing the error.

Comment: BTW, changing `DisplayMenu` to match `ChooseFromMenu` seems hacky. (`DisplayMenu`doesn't have to return value). Better would be to fix `ChooseFromMenu` and place `DisplayMenu()` before and inside the loop (after `cin.ignore`).

Comment: If it's used where compiler requires boolean condition... it is not hacky. DisplayMenu **HAS** to return value if it's used like that.

Comment: It can never return `false`, so the fact that `DisplayMenu()` returns is strange. You might use at calling site `(DisplayMenu(), true)` instead, but it is also strange.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, If you use it like this then you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a parenthesis in the while loop in ChooseFromMenu(). That is probably causing 2 of the errors. Since return true didn't work, you probably forgot to change the method header from void to boolean. (cin >> A) also returns void.

Comment: I changed displayMenu to bool and I added return A; but not working even return true not working

Comment: @davidfoster cin>>a also returns void

Comment: @AppWriter `cin >> A` will return `void*` and thus `!(cin >> A)` will return `0`. Meaning that `(DisplayMenu() && !(cin >> A))` will always return `0` value which in C/C++ is equal to `FALSE`.